# Always getting en error when debugging the code in stm32 cube

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I have created an new project, and didn't change anything. I just debug the code, but I am always getting an error like this:

```
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.14.0/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.100.202309141235/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot open linker script file C:\Users\Onur YaÃ„Å¸cÃ„Â±\Desktop\STM32 PROJECTS CUBE\STM32F401CB3\STM32F401CBUX_FLASH.ld: No such file or directory
```

collect2.exe: error:

```
 ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [makefile:88: STM32F401CB3.elf] Error 1

"make -j16 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

13:06:18 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 801ms)

How we can solve? Thanks

I didnt change anything on the code but its not debuggging correctly

Comment: Possibly the tools don't like spaces and/or unicode characters in your file path.

Comment: Since you're saying "didn't change the code" I get a feeling that you have copied an entire project folder. And it might getting the debug information from the copied files.
My suggestion would be that you delete the debug files and folder and let the IDE to make everything from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing comes from the presence of misinterpreted characters in your project path.

You can have spaces in it your path, however, not all characters are supported in CubeIDE 1.14.0. In particular, the national characters (your case here).

Your windows account on your computer is `Onur Yağcı`, resulting in your path being `C:\Users\Onur Yağcı\`. However, from CubeIDE point of view, it is recognized as `C:\Users\Onur YaÃ„Å¸cÃ„Â±\`.

By changing or removing all the misunderstood characters such as `C:\Users\Onur\`, your issue will be gone.

I'm quite surprise though that you arrived to the linker step. It should have failed at the compiler step, resulting in a "No such file or directory" error.